# 'xte mousedown' / '-up' via xbindkeys not working

Tags: mouse, xbindkeys, xte

I would like to bind my (Logitech mouse, thumb button) `b:2` to the middle mouse button `button 2`.

I tried

```
 "xte 'mouseclick 2'"
   b:8
```

which does work in the **terminal**, but not with xbindkeys.
Neither does the following trigger any action, which is what I actually planned to do:

```
 "xte 'mousedown 2'"
   b:8
 "xte 'mouseup 2'"
   b:8 + release
```

I can, however, send keystrokes as `"xte 'keydown A'"` using xbindkeys without any problems. If I replace `keydown A` with `mouseclick 2`, no mouse action is triggered. (I check it holding the mouse over a firefox tab and see if it gets closed)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I faced the same issue.

I fixed it by

```
"xte 'mouseclick 2'"
b:8+Release
```

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Thank you so much! Had the exact same problem. This worked (Linux Mint 17, Logitech Anywhere MX).